# Why is Kotlin throw IllegalArgumentException when using Proxy

Tags: java, kotlin, proxy-classes

This is the Kotlin equivalent of Java code using `InvocationHandler`:

```
override fun invoke(proxy: Any?, method: Method?, args: Array<out Any>?): Any {
    println("before httprequest--->" + args)
    val ret = method!!.invoke(obj, args)
    println("after httprequest--->")
    return ret
}
```

Java code:

```
public Object invoke(Object o, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("jdk--------->http" + args);
    Object  result=method.invoke(target, args);
    System.out.println("jdk--------->http");
    return result;
}
```

In both case `args` is null , But if I run it, Kotlin code is giving Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

What is the cause of this as Kotlin is using the standard Java class?

Comment: `wrong number of arguments`: did you look at the arguments in either case? Can you `assert` the length of the array before the call?

Comment: Hi @9000, both case 'args' is null before the print statement

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you pass `args` into `method!!.invoke(obj, args)` in Kotlin, it is actually a single argument of array type, and by default **it is not decomposed into its elements** as separate arguments.

To achieve that behavior instead, use the [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs): `*args`

```
val ret = method!!.invoke(obj, *args)
```

With this syntax, `args` will be passed in the same way as in Java varargs. For example, these lines of code are equivalent:

```
someVarargsFunction("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
someVarargsFunction("a", "b", *arrayOf("c", "d"), "e")
```

**Note:** if a method doesn't have any parameters, `args` will be `null`, and spreading it in Kotlin would result into a `NullPointerException`. As a workaround, use `*(args ?: arrayOfNulls<Any>(0))`, and in the described corner case the right part is chosen and spread into *zero* arguments.

---

My example proxy implementation:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    fun f(a: Int, b: Int): Int
}

val obj = object : SomeInterface {
    override fun f(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
}
```

```
val a = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        SomeInterface::class.java.classLoader,
        arrayOf(SomeInterface::class.java)) { proxy, method, args ->
    println("Before; args: " + args?.contentToString())
    val ret = method!!.invoke(obj, *(args ?: arrayOfNulls<Any>(0)))
    println("After; result: $ret")
    ret
} as SomeInterface

println(a.f(1, 2))
```

And the output is:

> ```
> Before; args: [1, 2]
> After; result: 3
> 3
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge, however if I just replace args with 'null', I'm getting the same Exception ? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @EugenPechanec same result :(

Comment: @EugenPechanec Interestingly `*arrayOfNulls<String>(0) ` worked! But why? Why is null not enough

Comment: @WenChao, it's just the same: because `null` as passed is *one* argument, while `*arrayOfNulls<String>(0)` is spread into none. :)

Comment: Also, updated the answer with an example proxy implementation.

Comment: I tried the code in the question using `*args` instead of just `args`. The latter produced an `IllegalArgumentException`, the former a `NullPointerException`.  This only happens when the function you're proxying is a void function, in whose case it looks like the array in question will be null.

Comment: @hotkey Yeah, in your example you have params in the function of the interface, mine doesn't have any param. So I can't use `*args` it will throw exception saying `Parameter specified as non-null is null`

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo you are right, I'm proxying a void function with no params

Comment: I think @hokey's answer is the right one. I will upvote now. It is just that in this case Kotlin's code will be more verbose, because we cannot spread a null array. Right?

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I've updated the answer with the corner case of `args == null` explanation.

Comment: @hotkey I guess that's probably the only solution for this now, does that mean Kotlin null is not the same as Java null at certain situation?

Comment: @WenChao, yes, it is not the same for varargs. For example, compare Java `varargFunction(null)` (`null` array reference is passed) with Kotlin `varargFunction(null)` (single item `null` is wrapped into an array and passed).

Comment: @hotkey Thanks ! You are really helpful