# Idiomatic way to invoke methods through reflection in Kotlin

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I have a piece of Kotlin code that is trying to reflectively invoke a method using Java's Reflection package:

```
val arguments = arrayOfNulls<Any>(numberOfParams)

// Populate arguments

try {
    fooMethod.invoke(fooClass, arguments)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // Panic
}
```

It keeps failing with an IllegalArgumentException of "wrong number of parameters".

I did some reading on the issue and it seems the spread operator of the `invoke()` method refuses to unpack `Array<Any>` because it's not equivalent to `Object[]`. I could try to use a standard `Object[]` from Java, but it makes me wonder, is this the only way? Is it the best way? Is there some way I can do this with Kotlin's types?

What is the most idomatic way to achieve what I want in Kotlin?

Comment: Please check if this answer helps: [(link)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41774675/2196460)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the spread operator `*` to your call:

```
fooMethod.invoke(fooClass, *arguments)
```

Using `arguments` without prefixing it with `*` will cause a new array of length 1 containing `arguments` as its single element to be created and passed as `args` to `invoke`. Prefixing it with the spread operator causes the `arguments` array to be passed to `invoke` as `args`.

See [Variable number of arguments (Varargs) - Functions - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) for more details.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now because I remember this operator existing but it completely slipped my mind. Sometimes a guy just needs a little push. Thank you.