# Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception. Cannot evaluate $Proxy0.toString()

Tags: java, android, kotlin, reflection

I'm trying to load an interface using reflection with this code :

```
val clazz : Class<Client> = Client::class.java
val classLoader = clazz.classLoader
val invocationHandler = ProviderInvocationHandler()

Proxy.newProxyInstance(classLoader, arrayOf(clazz), invocationHandler)
```

Here is my Client interface :

```
interface Client {
    fun getCustomer(id: String)
}
```

And my invocation handler :

```
private class ProviderInvocationHandler : InvocationHandler {

    override fun invoke(proxy: Any?, method: Method?, args: Array<out Any>?): Any {
        Log.d("Reflection", "Invocation handler")

        return method!!.invoke(proxy, args)
    }
}
```

Nothing append when I execute this code and `invoke` from the handler method is never call. But if I assign the value of `Proxy.newProxyInstance` in a variable, in my debugger I see this : `Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception. Cannot evaluate $Proxy0.toString()`

Don't understand why this exception is raised

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kotlin throw IllegalArgumentException when using Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774450/why-is-kotlin-throw-illegalargumentexception-when-using-proxy)

Comment: and maybe you didn't want to call the method on the proxy, but rather on the actual target object itself?